# "Unable to get Schema of a Component"

Tags: 2011, core-service, schema, java

I am new To tridion. I am trying a Java program which automatically uploads the image into tridion when an image is selected from the local machine. I have written the following code.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.CoreService2011;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreService;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServiceGetSystemWideListCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.IStreamUpload;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.BinaryContentData;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.ComponentData;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.ComponentType;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.IdentifiableObjectData;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.ItemType;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.LinkToMultimediaTypeData;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.LinkToSchemaData;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.ObjectFactory;
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.ReadOptions;

public class FileUpload {
    public static void main(String args[])
            throws ICoreServiceGetSystemWideListCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage {
        CoreService2011 service = new CoreService2011();
        ICoreService client = service.getBasicHttp();


        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        String IdRefDec;


        try {

            ComponentData multimediaComponent = (ComponentData) client
                    .getDefaultData(ItemType.COMPONENT, "tcm:246-95-2");


            LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = new LinkToSchemaData();
            linkToSchemaData.setIdRef(objectFactory.createLinkIdRef("tcm:246-243-8"));


            ComponentType componentType = null;
            componentType = componentType.MULTIMEDIA;
            multimediaComponent.setComponentType(objectFactory
                    .createComponentType(componentType));
            multimediaComponent.setTitle(objectFactory
                    .createLinkTitle("MMComponent"));

            multimediaComponent.setSchema(objectFactory.createLinkToSchemaData(linkToSchemaData));

            System.out.println(multimediaComponent.getSchema().toString());

            String myFilename = "Chrysanthemum.jpg";

            System.out.println("Myfile name done");

            String extension = myFilename
                    .substring(myFilename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            System.out.println("extension: " + extension);

            String tempPath = "";

            IStreamUpload iStreamUpload = service.getStreamUploadBasicHttp();
            System.out.println("istreamupload");

            // UploadRequest uploadRequest = new UploadRequest();

            File file = new File(
                    "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\images\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
            String s = file.toString();

            byte[] myByte = new byte[4096];

            InputStream ios = new FileInputStream(file);

            ByteArrayOutputStream ous = null;

            try {

                ous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                int read = 0;

                while ((read = ios.read(myByte)) != -1) {

                    ous.write(myByte, 0, read);

                }

            } finally {

                if (ous != null)

                    ous.close();

                if (ios != null)

                    ios.close();

            }

            // uploadRequest.setUploadContent(ous.toByteArray());

            tempPath = iStreamUpload.uploadBinaryByteArray(s

            , myByte);

            System.out.println(tempPath);

            System.out.println(multimediaComponent.getSchema().getName());

            BinaryContentData binaryContentData = new BinaryContentData();
            binaryContentData.setUploadFromFile(objectFactory
                    .createLinkTitle(tempPath));
            binaryContentData.setFilename(objectFactory
                    .createBinaryContentDataFilename(myFilename));
            System.out
                    .println(binaryContentData.getUploadFromFile().getValue());

            // if (extension == ".png")
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-3-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".jpeg")
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-2-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpg") ||
            // extension.equalsIgnoreCase(".jpeg"))
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-2-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else if (extension == ".bmp")
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-13-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else if (extension == ".gif")
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-1-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else if (extension == ".ico")
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "tcm:0-35-65544";
            //
            // }
            // else
            // {
            // IdRefDec = "";
            // }

            LinkToMultimediaTypeData multimediaTypeData = new LinkToMultimediaTypeData();
            multimediaTypeData.setIdRef(objectFactory
                    .createLinkIdRef("tcm:0-2-65544"));


            binaryContentData.setMultimediaType(objectFactory
                    .createLinkToMultimediaTypeData(multimediaTypeData));
            multimediaComponent.setBinaryContent(objectFactory
                    .createBinaryContentData(binaryContentData));
            IdentifiableObjectData savedComponent = client.create(
                    multimediaComponent, new ReadOptions());
            savedComponent.getId();
            // client.checkIn(savedComponent.getId(), new ReadOptions());

        } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
  }
```

When I try to run the above code, it is giving the below exception

```
Exception :
com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.ICoreServiceCreateCoreServiceFaultFaultFaultMessage: Unable to get Schema of Component.
```

Can any one help me in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance........

Comment: Does the schema 'tcm:246-243-8' exist?

Comment: Can you show the results of the logging you've coded - this would help to confirm where exactly in the code it is failing?

Comment: @johnwinter : Yes john the schema exists.

Comment: Refer this stack overflow question: 
http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1142/setting-schema-reference-for-multimedia-component-in-java?lq=1

It may help you..

Comment: @Deepika : Thanks for your post. Actually, I have only posted that question on how to set the link to schema.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the Java proxy you are using, but it looks a bit odd that you already have a `LinkToSchemaData`, and then instead of using it directly, you pass it to `createLinkToSchemaData()`.

Comment: LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = new LinkToSchemaData();
linkToSchemaData.setIdRef(objectFactory.createLinkIdRef("tcm:246-243-8"));  
multimediaComponent.setSchema(objectFactory.createLinkToSchemaData(linkToSchemaData));                                                                  LinkToSchemaData is a class in Tridion and CreateLinkToSchemaData is a method in ObjectFactory which we use when we want to create a JAXBElement.   
Here the linkToSchemaData.setIdRef(objectFactory.createLinkIdRef("tcm:246-243-8")); accepts JAXBElement so I have used that statement.