# Setting Schema reference for Multimedia Component in Java

Tags: 2011, core-service, java

I have used the below code to set Default Multimedia Schema while creating a multimedia Component.

```java
ComponentData multimediaComponent = (ComponentData) client.getDefaultData(ItemType.COMPONENT, "tcm:246-95-2");
LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = new LinkToSchemaData();
linkToSchemaData.setIdRef(objectFactory.createLinkIdRef("tcm:246-243-8"));
multimediaComponent.setSchema(objectFactory.createLinkToSchemaData(linkToSchemaData));
```

When I try to run the code I have noticed that the Schema is not correctly set.
Can anyone suggest me if there is any other way I can set the Schema reference to create a multimedia Component in SDL Tridion or is there anything I need to change in the above code?

Comment: This appears to be related to http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1125/129 although I'm not sure if it should be a duplicate. Are you asking the same question two different ways? :-)

Comment: @DominicCronin : Yes, Domnic. Actually I am facing an issue with setting the schema to multimedia component. So I have posted only the Code where in I am creating a link to multimedia schema. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You mention that the Schema is not correctly set, what exactly does that mean? It would help a lot if you could specify where you get an error (compile time or runtime and with what details/stack trace?).

I'm not so familiar with the Core Service Java API, but I was under the impression you could simply set the Schema as follows (no need to use the `objectFactory` twice in there):

```java
LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = new LinkToSchemaData();
linkToSchemaData.IdRef = "tcm:246-243-8";
multimediaComponent.setSchema(linkToSchemaData);
```

When reading the example in the documentation (which is using the `objectFactory`), it would translate to something like this I think:

```java
LinkToSchemaData linkToSchemaData = objectFactory.createLinkToSchemaData();
linkToSchemaData.setIdRef(objectFactory.createLinkIdRef("tcm:246-243-8"));
multimediaComponent.setSchema(objectFactory.createComponentDataSchema(linkToSchemaData));
```

Comment: When I try to save the multimedia component it is raising an exception - "Unable to get Schema of component".

Comment: In Java we dont have the method ".IdRef". We have ".setIdRef()" which accepts a JAXBElement<String> as a parameter. So I created Object factory to setIdRef.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how you create your proxy, see also Mihai's articles on using the Core Service in Java http://yatb.mitza.net/search/label/Core%20Service