# Where to get the JARs for sdltridion.contentmanager

Tags: 2011, core-service, java

(I asked this question on stackoverflow and they pointed me to the existence of tridion.stackexchange.com, so I repost it here.)

For our automated tests I want to connect to Tridion from our Java testsuite we setup with Cucumber. I want to do this through a webservice. There is a manual on sdllivecontent.com on how to do this, but when I try to get the appropriate .jar files, I can't find them.

The manual from sdllivecontent.com tells me:

> Add the following import statements to your proxy client class:

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;  
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.coreservice.*;  
import com.sdltridion.contentmanager.r6.*;
```

The latter two get not recognized, so I have to get the correct references.
I added the following Tridion jar files as libraries to my project structure:

- C:\Program Files\Tridion\lib
- C:\Software\Tridion\Content Delivery\roles\api\java\lib
- C:\Software\Tridion\Content Delivery\roles\api\java\third-party-lib

And now I can import from `com.tridion.*`, but still not from `com.sdltridion.*`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SDL owned packages always start with `com.tridion.*` or `com.sdl.*`, not with `com.sdltridion.*` (and especially not `com.sdltridion.contentmanager.*`).

It seems like you're using custom jars (maybe [from here](https://code.google.com/p/yet-another-tridion-blog/source/browse/#svn/trunk/Core%20Service%20Java%20Client/src/com/sdltridion/contentmanager)?) and you should keep track - or contact the author - of those.

**Update** I just found the chapter in [the documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CF2ABF27-2D1C-4342-9635-2DFD7A6D4D42) you mention and it also states

> To get the Java proxy client up and running, generate a proxy (Java XmlBeans is recommended as a proxy generator)

In other words, you need to generate the classes yourself by pointing at the Core Service's WSDL.

Mihai has some examples of how to do this on [his blog](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/12/a-core-service-java-client.html).

Comment: The manual I try to follow is from https://sdltridionworld.com/. As I could see from this question: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/unable-to-get-schema-of-a-component?rq=1, so it seems there are more people using it with these imports.

Comment: Updated my answer - those jars don't exist pre-packaged, you need to generate them.

Comment: Thank you for finding that. I created the proxy client, but was oblivious of the fact that it would create the classes.
I will try the steps from the blog and update my findings.

Comment: This solved it for me. I tried to generate the files through the manual I linked earlier, but that didn't quite work out. So I did it through the method from the blog you posted and that worked fine.